# How to serialize integer to ApplicationDataContainer

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10

I am porting an old game to Windows 10 store app.
I can write and then read string to app settings:

```
ApplicationDataContainer^ localSettings = ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings;

localSettings->Values->Insert("keyS", "hello");
String^ valueS = safe_cast<String^>(localSettings->Values->Lookup("keyS"));
```

I also can put `int` value:

```
localSettings->Values->Insert("keyI", 123);
```

But how do I read it?

```
??? valueI = safe_cast<???>(localSettings->Values->Lookup("keyI"));
```

`Lookup` returns `Platform::Object^`, so how do I cast it to `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an `IBox` -- the equivalent of "nullable" in .NET.

```cpp
auto localSettings = ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings;
localSettings->Values->Insert(L"forty-two", (int)42);
auto forty_two = static_cast<Platform::IBox<int>^>
  (localSettings->Values->Lookup(L"forty-two"));
if (forty_two != nullptr)
{
  int value = forty_two->Value;
  // use value
}
```